# Organize table in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I had already asked a similar question before, but I tried to adapt it to my code and it did not work well.

I have the following code that paints a table in PHP, I want to show the `PRODUCT` total when I detect `PRODUCT` change, I have tried to do the following, but it shows me the `TOTAL` row at the beginning of each `PRODUCT` and does not totalize well

The variables `GOLD`, `NORMAL` are dynamic, i.e. there may be tables that do not have `GOLD`, like others that do not have `NORMAL`:

This is my code:

```
<?php

$harvest = Array ( 
       Array ( 
                     Array ( 
                                    'PRODUCT' => 'ROSE' ,
                                    'VARIETY' => 'ADELE', 
                                  'GOLD' => 160, 
                                    'NORMAL' => 0 ,
                                    'TOTAL' => 160 
                                  ) ,
                     Array ( 
                                    'PRODUCT' => 'ROSE',
                                    'VARIETY' => 'ALESSO' ,
                                    'GOLD' => 1320 ,
                                    'NORMAL' => 550, 
                                    'TOTAL' => 1870 
                                  ) ,
                     Array ( 
                                    'PRODUCT' => 'ROSE',
                                    'VARIETY' => 'ANASTACIA' ,
                                    'GOLD' => 440 ,
                                    'NORMAL' => 150 ,
                                    'TOTAL' => 590 
                                  ),
                     Array ( 
                                    'PRODUCT' => 'ROSE1',
                                  'VARIETY' => 'ANASTACIA1' ,
                                  'GOLD' => 420 ,
                                    'NORMAL' => 120 ,
                                    'TOTAL' => 540 
                                  ),
                     Array ( 
                                    'PRODUCT' => 'ROSE1',
                                    'VARIETY' => 'ANASTACIA1', 
                                    'GOLD' => 440 ,
                                    'NORMAL' => 100 ,
                                    'TOTAL' => 540 
                                  ),
                     Array ( 
                                    'PRODUCT' => 'ROSE2',
                                    'VARIETY' => 'ANASTACIA2',
                                    'GOLD' => 640, 
                                    'NORMAL' => 0, 
                                    'TOTAL' => 640 
                                  ),
                     Array ( 
                                    'PRODUCT' => 'ROSE2',
                                    'VARIETY' => 'ANASTACIA2' ,
                                    'GOLD' => 440, 
                                    'NORMAL' => 440, 
                                    'TOTAL' => 880 
                                   )
                    )


     );

$arrayThead = array();
      for ($i=0; $i < count($harvest) ; $i++) {
        array_push($arrayThead, array_keys($harvest[$i][0]));
      }

      $totalByProduct = array();
      foreach ($harvest as $items) {
          foreach ($items as $item) {
              if(!key_exists($item['PRODUCT'], $totalByProduct)){
                  $totalByProduct[$item['PRODUCT']] = $item;
                  continue;
              }
              foreach ($arrayThead as $key => $values) {
                foreach ($values as $th) {
                  if($th != 'PRODUCT' && $th != 'VARIETY'){
                    $totalByProduct[$item['PRODUCT']][$th] += $item[$th];
                  }
                }
              }
          }
      }
      $arrayfoot= array();

      foreach ($harvest as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $harv) {
          foreach ($arrayThead as $key => $values) {
            foreach ($values as $th) {
              if($th != 'PRODUCT' && $th != 'VARIETY'){
                  $arrayfoot[$th] += $harv[$th];
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

      $arrayComplete = array();
      for ($i=0; $i < count($arrayThead) ; $i++) {
        for ($j=0; $j < count($arrayThead[$i]) ; $j++) {
          if($arrayThead[$i][$j] != 'PRODUCT' && $arrayThead[$i][$j] != 'VARIETY'){
            array_push($arrayComplete, $arrayThead[$i][$j]);
          }
        }
      }


      $arrayFinal = array();
      for ($j=0; $j < count($arrayComplete) ; $j++) {
        array_push($arrayFinal, $arrayfoot[$arrayComplete[$j]]);
      }

      $body = '<table style="border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;width: 100%;font-family:Calibri;">';
      $body .= '<thead style="background-color:#f3f4f5;">';
      $body .= '<tr>';

      for ($i=0; $i < count($arrayThead) ; $i++) {
        for ($j=0; $j < count($arrayThead[$i]) ; $j++) {
          if($arrayThead[$i][$j] === 'PRODUCT' || $arrayThead[$i][$j] === 'VARIETY'){
            $body .= '<th style="border: 1px solid black;height:50px;">'.$arrayThead[$i][$j].'</th>';
          }else{
            $body .= '<th style="border: 1px solid black;height:50px;">'.$arrayThead[$i][$j].'</th>';
          }
        }
      }
      $body .= '</tr>';
      $body .= '</thead>';
      $body .= '<tbody>';

//Initialize the variable product
      $product = "";
      foreach ($harvest as $items) {
          foreach ($items as $item) {

//If the $product variable is different from the data product, print the total

          if($product != $item['PRODUCT']){
              $body .= '<tr>';
              $body .= '<th style="border: 1px solid black;text-align:left;font-size:12px;">TOTAL '.$item['PRODUCT'].'</th>';
              $body .= '<th style="border: 1px solid black;text-align:left;font-size:12px;"></th>';

              foreach ($arrayThead as $key => $values) {
                foreach ($values as $th) {
                  if($th != 'PRODUCT' && $th != 'VARIETY'){
                    $body .= '<th style="border: 1px solid black;text-align:right;font-size:12px;">'.number_format($total).'</th>';
                  }
                }
              }
              $body .= '</tr>';
              $product = $item['PRODUCT'];
          }
          $body .= '<tr>';
          foreach ($arrayThead as $key => $values) {
            foreach ($values as $th) {
              if($th === 'PRODUCT' || $th === 'VARIETY'){
                $body .= '<td style="border: 1px solid black;font-size:12px;">'.$item[$th].'</td>';
              }else{
                $body .= '<td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align:right;font-size:12px;">'.number_format($item[$th]).'</td>';
              }
            }
          }
          $body .= '</tr>';
          $product = $item['PRODUCT'];
        }
      }

      $body .= '</tbody>';
      $body .= '<tfoot>';
      $body .= '<tr>';
      $body .= '<th style="border: 1px solid black;text-align:left;">TOTAL GENERAL</th>';
      $body .= '<th style="border: 1px solid black;"></th>';

      for ($i=0; $i < count($arrayFinal) ; $i++) {
        $body .= '<th style="border: 1px solid black;text-align:right;">'.number_format($arrayFinal[$i]).'</th>';
      }

      $body .= '</tr>';
      $body .= '</tfoot>';
      $body .= '</table>';

      echo $body;
```

To see how it works, please copy and paste the code on the following page:

[PHPTester](http://phptester.net/)

I hope that someone can help me.

Comment: What's the problem? Please reduce amount of code to create a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You can copy and paste the code in the link PHPTester, you can see my problem! @k0pernikus

Comment: You want the help of the community. So please provide the necessary information within the question, and don't expect us to do the work for you.

Comment: I am sorry but this is the way that I can show you how my code works! @k0pernikus and I don´t want that someone do all the work for me!

Comment: Sorry I dont understand your question. May be you are making things complicated when it should not.  As I understand you want a table with these headers 'PRODUCT' ,  'VARIETY' ,  'GOLD'  ,   'NORMAL', TOTAL been the total always gold + normal... please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: It is right @NoelCarcases. I am sorry I am trying to be more clear with the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are looking for something like this

```
    <?
$harvest = Array ( 
     Array ( 
                    'PRODUCT' => 'ROSE' ,
                    'VARIETY' => 'ADELE', 
                    'GOLD' => 160, 
                    'NORMAL' => 0 ,
                    'TOTAL' => 160 
                  ) ,
     Array ( 
                    'PRODUCT' => 'ROSE',
                    'VARIETY' => 'ALESSO' ,
                    'GOLD' => 1320 ,
                    'NORMAL' => 550, 
                    'TOTAL' => 1870 
                  ) ,
     Array ( 
                    'PRODUCT' => 'ROSE',
                    'VARIETY' => 'ANASTACIA' ,
                    'GOLD' => 440 ,
                    'NORMAL' => 150 ,
                    'TOTAL' => 590 
                  ),
     Array ( 
                    'PRODUCT' => 'ROSE1',
                  'VARIETY' => 'ANASTACIA1' ,
                  'GOLD' => 420 ,
                    'NORMAL' => 120 ,
                    'TOTAL' => 540 
                  ),
     Array ( 
                    'PRODUCT' => 'ROSE1',
                    'VARIETY' => 'ANASTACIA1', 
                    'GOLD' => 440 ,
                    'NORMAL' => 100 ,
                    'TOTAL' => 540 
                  ),
     Array ( 
                    'PRODUCT' => 'ROSE2',
                    'VARIETY' => 'ANASTACIA2',
                    'GOLD' => 640, 
                    'NORMAL' => 0, 
                    'TOTAL' => 640 
                  ),
     Array ( 
                    'PRODUCT' => 'ROSE2',
                    'VARIETY' => 'ANASTACIA2' ,
                    'GOLD' => 440, 
                    'NORMAL' => 440, 
                    'TOTAL' => 880 
                   )

 );


 //You will endup with a products array indexed by product name
 $products = [];

 $general = Array('GOLD' => 0,'NORMAL' => 0, 'TOTAL' => 0);
 foreach ($harvest as $items) {
    $general["GOLD"] += $items["GOLD"];
    $general["NORMAL"] += $items["NORMAL"];
    $general["TOTAL"] += $items["TOTAL"];
    if (array_key_exists($items["PRODUCT"],$products)){
        $products[$items["PRODUCT"]]["TOTALS"]["GOLD-TOTAL"] += $items["GOLD"];
        $products[$items["PRODUCT"]]["TOTALS"]["NORMAL-TOTAL"] += $items["NORMAL"];
        $products[$items["PRODUCT"]]["TOTALS"]["TOTAL"] += $items["TOTAL"];
        array_push($products[$items["PRODUCT"]],$items);
    }
    else{
        $totals=[];
        $totals["GOLD-TOTAL"] = 0;
        $totals["NORMAL-TOTAL"] = 0;
        $totals["TOTAL"] = 0;
        $totals["NAME"] = $items["PRODUCT"];
        $products[$items["PRODUCT"]]=[$items];
        $products[$items["PRODUCT"]]["TOTALS"] = $totals;
    }
 }
```

?>

```
<table>
<thead>
    <th>PRODUCT</th>
    <th>VARIETY</th>
    <th>GOLD</th>
    <th>NORMAL</th>
    <th>TOTAL</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?foreach ($products as $product) { 
        foreach ($product as $item){
            if (array_key_exists("PRODUCT",$item)){
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?print($item["PRODUCT"])?></td>
        <td><?print($item["VARIETY"])?></td>
        <td><?print($item["GOLD"])?></td>
        <td><?print($item["NORMAL"])?></td>
        <td><?print($item["TOTAL"])?></td>
    </tr>
    <?}}?>
    <tr>
        <td>Total <? print($product["TOTALS"]["NAME"])?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><? print($product["TOTALS"]["GOLD-TOTAL"])?></td>
        <td><? print($product["TOTALS"]["NORMAL-TOTAL"])?></td>
        <td><? print($product["TOTALS"]["TOTAL"])?></td>
    </tr>
    <?}?>
    <tr>
        <td>TOTAL GENERAL</td>
        <td></td>
        <td><?print($general["GOLD"])?></td>
        <td><?print($general["NORMAL"])?></td>
        <td><?print($general["TOTAL"])?></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I try this one instead for my code http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Comment: ok I check your code now I know what you are asking. I will edit my answer

Comment: I have edited the code to suits your needs, its a shorted implementation of your code I really dont know how to fix yours sorry :D

Comment: Thanks for your answer!